# how to plot axis invisible while plotting wordcloud

Tags: python

Method plt.axis() shows error as string object is not callable

I tried to re run the code to check if any plt axis is already used but invain

Comment: Are you using `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1):

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,10),facecolor = 'none', edgecolor='white')
plt.imshow(lem_word_cloud)
plt.title("Lemming Cloud of Train Data")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show();
"still not sure why was the error. Now it is working after restarting"
```